# C# string method ToLowerInvariant()

Tags: c#, .net

I want to count a particular character as shown in the code

but it seems to be case-sensitive. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code? Thanks

```
class ClassTwo
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        ClassTwo ct = new ClassTwo();
        Console.WriteLine(ct.GetCountLetters("canada", 'A'));
    }

    int GetCountLetters(string text, char c)
    {
        int count = 0;
        text = text.ToLowerInvariant();
        char[] chars = text.ToCharArray();    // 'c'  'a'  'n'  'a' 'd' 'a'
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
        {
            if (chars[i] == c)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're lowering the text but passing a cap char. What do you *need* it to do?

Comment: Yes, character comparisons are case-sensitive. A simple fix would be `if (chars[i] == c.ToLowerInvariant())`

Comment: Thanks, a lot! @ D Stanley for the idea

Now, here is the working one:

 if (chars[i] == char.ToLowerInvariant(c))
                {
                    count++;
                }

Comment: Side note: it might be useful to pull the `ToLowerInvariant()` calls out of `GetCountLetters` so that the caller can determine how it should be compared. Also, you can simplify that a lot with: `text.Count(x => x == c);`